# experience internal error in in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

[image]

I have kept my machine on sleep and then when i open it up it became very laggy and become so slow to use.Previously it use to run so smooth.I dont think its beacouse of hardware as it has got  ssd and good  ram.After some time i showed a message as in picture and when i restarted it it still working slow.What might be the reason and how to solve

Comment: To see details, click on the "Show Details" button.

Comment: Error solved itself afer sometime.